# display table entries on page 2 when selected in page 1

Tags: wpf

I want to select "Name" from a combobox on home.xaml. When I do this I want "Name address and age" to fill another page. I can display this easily when on the same page.

At the moment cbParts is not being recognised

```
string Query = "select * from Parts where Name='" + cbParts.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ;";
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to use two pages or UserControls?
If you're using UserControls, it's a classic Master - Details scenario, you can find an example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application.

If you want to use pages, you'll have to pass the parameter as the second page's DataContext. If you create the second page in the first it's easy enough. If not you'll need some common object to pass the information, you can try a MVVM framework like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which have a messenger for exactly these situations.

Regards,
Yoni.